# tkinter .after method to make text box look like it's scrolling

Tags: tkinter, delay

I am having trouble understanding how to apply the .after method.

My application uses a tk.text widget to display messages to the user. It adds them to the end of the text and scrolls once the window is full. The problem I'm trying to get around is that the message is often eactly the same as the previous one, so there is no visual cue that anyting has changed. The messages are several lines long, so I want to introduce a short delay between each line so the user can see it scrolling.

I have tried several methods. Part of the issue is that I don't really need to have the .after call a function; I just want it to wait between lines in my code. But even using it to call functions as I have in the code below it doesn't do what I want. This now waits for all the delays to occur before it does anything at all.

Can this be made to work, or is there a better way  of achieving my goal?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

# root window
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('300x200')

def line2():
    messages.insert("end", "line 2\n" )
    messages.see('end')
    
def line3():
    messages.insert("end", "line 3\n" )
    messages.see('end')
    
def line4():
    messages.insert("end", "line 4\n" )
    messages.see('end')

messages = tk.Text(root, height=3)
messages.grid(sticky='ewns')
messages.config(state="normal")

messages.insert("end", "line 1\n" )
messages.see('end')
messages.after(1000,line2())
messages.after(1000,line3())
messages.after(1000,line4())

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You aren't actually delaying anything.  `messages.after(1000,line2())` calls `line2` *right now* (that's what the parentheses after the function name mean!), and then one second later tries to execute None (the return value of the function).  You need to pass the function name alone there.  Also, you either need to use increasing delays for the other two functions, or start their delay from the previous function instead of your main code.

Comment: Thank you! That seems to have got this demo program working, now to see if I can apply to my program.